# Confirming an inconsistency of the Balitsky-Kovchegov equation between references

Tags: particle-physics, quantum-chromodynamics

I'm comparing the form of the Balitsky-Kovchegov equation, which describes the splitting of low-momentum gluons, between different references, and I'm finding an inconsistency: most sources ([1](http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-ph/0111244), [2](http://arxiv.org/abs/0710.4330), [3](http://arxiv.org/abs/1203.6139), [4](http://arxiv.org/abs/1401.0313), [5](http://www.cambridge.org/us/academic/subjects/physics/particle-physics-and-nuclear-physics/quantum-chromodynamics-high-energy?format=HB), etc.) give the relevant part of the equation as
$$\frac{\alpha_s N_c}{2\pi^2}\iint\mathrm{d}^2\vec{b}\frac{r^2}{s^2 t^2}\bigl[N(s) + N(t) - N(r) - N(s)N(t)\bigr]\tag{1}$$
where the coordinates are related to each other by
$$\begin{align}
\vec{r} &= \vec{x} - \vec{y} &
\vec{s} &= \vec{x} - \vec{b} &
\vec{t} &= \vec{y} - \vec{b}
\end{align}$$

[image: dipole coordinates]

(ignore the colors) and $\vec{x}$ and $\vec{y}$ are fixed. But [one paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-ph/0110325), which happens to be my main reference for the specific issue I'm looking at, gives the equation in the form
$$\frac{\alpha_s N_c}{\pi^2}\iint\mathrm{d}^2\vec{t}\biggl[\frac{r^2}{s^2 t^2} N(s) - \frac{r^2}{(s^2 + t^2)t^2}N(r) - \frac{1}{2}\frac{r^2}{s^2 t^2}N(s)N(t)\biggr]\tag{2}$$
Is this equivalent to the other form, specifically the middle term?

Changing the integration variable from $\vec{t}$ to $\vec{b}$ presents no problems (the Jacobian is $1$), and the $N(s)N(t)$ terms in both equations are obviously the same. I can also split the $N(s)$ term of equation (2) in half, and transform one half using $\vec{x} \leftrightarrow \vec{y}$ (thus turning $\vec{s}$ into $\vec{t}$), which accounts for the first two terms of equation (1). It looks like the remaining terms, proportional to $N(r)$, are not the same, but I can't quite rule out some coordinate transformation that makes them equivalent. Can anyone either prove that they're not the same, or find a physically valid transformation which shows that they are?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We start by rewriting the second version. Switching back to an integral over $\vec b$ and factoring out the same prefactor as in the first equation, we find

$$ \frac{\alpha_sN_c}{2\pi^2}\iint \mathrm d^2 \vec b \frac{r^2}{s^2t^2}\big[2N(s)-\frac{2s^2}{s^2+t^2}N(r)-N(s)N(t)\big]$$

Using the fact that we can split the $2N(s)$ into $N(s)+N(t)$, as you already noted, all the terms but one already coincide. The only difference is the term proportional to $N(r)$. The coefficient in the first equation is $-1$, but in the second it is

$$-\frac{2s^2}{s^2+t^2}\overset{!}{=}-\frac{s^2+t^2}{s^2+t^2}=-1$$

Here, the crucial step once again uses the $s\leftrightarrow t$ symmetry. Thus, the two formulae are seen to be equivalent.